# How to store values in an array and use it later in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I would like to know how to store a value from XML to an array variable in XSL and use those arrays to create a new XML file.

Using XSL version 1.0, here's an example:

Convert sample1.xml TO sample2.xml using XSL

sample1.xml

```
<root>
    <transfer>A</transfer>
    <station>A</station>
    <transfer>B</transfer>
    <station>B</station>
    <transfer>C</transfer>
    <station>C</station>    
</root>
```

sample2.xml

```
<root>
    <fund>A</fund>
    <place>A</place>
    <fund>B</fund>
    <place>B</place>
    <fund>C</fund>
    <place>C</place>    
</root>
```

So I need to store all the values from the `<transfer>` tag to an array and put the values into the `<fund>` tag.

So far I extracted values from one XML file and put the values in another XML file.

How can I put these items into an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As noted by Jeff Mercado, you don't need to store any values to solve the task at hand,** because overriding the identity rule with two ranaming templates produces the wanted result.

However, in other tasks having an "array"-like capability comes handy.

Generally, you can define a variable to contain a specific set of nodes and these can be accessed by their position (in document order), specifying this position in a predicate.

**Here is an example**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vTransfers" select="/*/transfer"/>
```

defines a variable named `vTransfers` with value the node-set of all `transfer` elements each of which is a child of the top element of the XML document.

**Then**:

```
$vTransfers[1]
```

selects the first element that is contained in `$vTransfers`.

```
$vTransfers[2]
```

selects the second element that is contained in `$vTransfers`, ...

```
$vTransfers[position() = $k]
```

selects the node from `$vTransfers` whose position, in document order, is equal to the value contained in the variable `$k`.

Comment: THANKS AND MORE I LEARNT VARIABLE ALSO CAN BE USED AS ARRAY IN XSL. STILL HAVE LOT EXPLORE IN XSL LEARNING ONE BY ONE. THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you would need an array.  You're just renaming the elements.  Just use these transforms:

```
<xsl:template match="transfer">
  <fund><xsl:value-of select="."/></fund>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="station">
  <place><xsl:value-of select="."/></place>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT I WAS ABOUT TO USE ARRAY CONCEPT STORING A VALUE BUT THESE ARE EASIER. THANKS AND MORE I LEARNT VARIABLE ALSO CAN BE USED AS ARRAY IN XSL